# Overflow Scrolling on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, scroll, overflow

To clip my webpage to the screen, I use this code in CSS:

```
html, body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

However, when scrolling on iOS, the page becomes choppy. I tried using this code:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

All it did for me is change overflow-x to scroll (although with overflow-x is scrollable, the page scrolls smoothly). I have also tried putting the code above as a style in HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When using:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

You must also set:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not fix the problem. It seems that this is also affecting scrolling on other desktop browsers as well. The problem is that without the code the pseudo-elements stretch way beyond the edge.

Comment: So the problem is not smooth scrolling it's that the content overflows?  Can you post the full code or an example or screenshot?

Comment: Here, this is the same problem I'm facing. If you look at this page in Chrome (or another webkit browser): [link](http://cssr.ru/simpliste/#simplesoft), the pseudo-elements cause the page to be able to scroll for quite a bit horizontally ([link](https://github.com/rafikov/Simpliste/issues/2)). I fixed this by using the code above, but ran into a slight scrolling issue. When using the code above, the scrolling gets choppy. Thanks for all your help.